# Recreate solution/project from DotPeek (or equivalents)?

Tags: c#, .net

I kinda accidently deleted a huge project I started years ago and have been working on it several days per week since.

I had 2 backups. A DVD backup and an External HDD backup. The external HDD has failed, and for some reason the damn DVD cannot be read anymore. The DVD looks to be in perfect condition, but will not work in any PC I put it in.

I've downloaded some free C# programs to help me get back my source code (I still have the app installed). So far, DotPeek seems to be the easiest to work with for me. But this project is so big, there's almost 3,000 class files and I can't just copy paste into a new project. It'll take me years!

How can I convert this back into a Visual Studio Solution/Project?

Comment: Wow that sounds like it sucks. I hope your project ends up fine!

Answer (score 7):

I am using DotPeek 1.2 To create a visual studio project you can just right click on the Assembly in `Assembly Explorer` and click `Export to Project...`

Comment: Is there a way to export multiple assemblies to a single solution file ?